# .htaccess How to check if URI + file extension doesn't exists before RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When a page is accessed via an URL like this:

/pagename

How can we check if the following file exists via htaccess

/pagename.htm

And then load index.php if not?

Here's what I'm working with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I've tried a variation of this but no luck:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.htm -f

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# If the URI is not .htm and doesn't have any additonal params, try .htm
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?![^/]+\.htm)([^/]+)$ $1.htm [L,R=302]
# Adding the R flag causes the URI to be rewritten in the browser rather than just internally

# If the URI is .htm but it doesn't exist, pass to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+\.htm)$ $1/no [L]

# Passes requested path as 'q' to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/no/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Should work rather elegantly for you. If it can't find the file, it just passes it on to index.php. You can of course modify what variable it uses, I just used 'q' for generic purposes.

Also, do note that you can condense this down to a single set of RewriteConds. I've expanded them for annotation purposes here.

Comment: The above solution works great but now I have a duplicate issue of having two URLs (with and without .htm)

How can I redirect /pagename to /pagename.htm as 301 if the file does exist?

Comment: Oh, if you want to redirect these, just change the `[L]` in the first rule to `[L,R=302]`. (If that does what you want it to after testing it, make it `[L,R=301]` to make it permanent.)

Comment: What I wanted to know was how I can redirect /pagename to /pagename.html in the browser URL. So no matter how you access it, you'll land on .htm (that is when the file does exist). Thanks,

Comment: The change I suggested should do just that. I'll edit my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks Dambrisco... one last question. Your solution doesn't respect deep links like /foldername/pagename.htm. You you please advise

Comment: Copy this into the .htaccess for each folder. That's the easiest and most direct way.

Comment: great trick for calling static content generated from a dynamic script. Via the same route I can generate the static version on-demand. Purge as necessary